# Strings and Memory Management

Tags: java, android, string, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having a hard time trying to understand what is going on with Strings and memory management in Android (Java).

To simplify, have a look at this simple piece of code:

```
public void createArray(){
        String s = "";
        String foo = "foo";
        String lorem = "Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum 
                 fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an.";
        ArrayList<Item> array = new ArrayList<Item>();

        for( int i=0; i<20000; i++ ){
            s = foo.replace("foo", lorem);
            array.add( new Item(s) );
        }
        System.gc();
    }

private class Item{
    String name;

    public Item(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If executed, `createArray` will allocate more than 5Mb in memory. Even with the `System.gc()` instruction, memory won't be deallocated after the loop.

Now, if we replace `s = foo.replace("foo", lorem);` with `s = lorem;`, allocated memory will only increase by 0.5Mb.

I need to understand what is going on to improve my application's performance.

Can anybody explain how should I replace Strings in a case like this? And why is `System.gc()` not deallocating memory?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks for the answers, now I understand that `System.gc()` is only a hint.

To clarify the other question (the important one):

How can I dynamically generate 20000 Strings ("foo1", "foo2"... "foo20000") add them to the ArrayList and do not run out of memory? If this 20000 strings were static they wouldn't allocate more than 0.5Mb in memory. Besides, if `s = foo.replace("foo", lorem)` creates a brand new String, why my function allocates 5Mb which is 10 times more memory? Shouldn't be around 1Mb?

(I am already thinking in a workaround but I want to be sure there is no way to generate the strings dynamically without using this huge amount of memory)

Comment: at the end of your for-loop put `array = null`. That should free up references for GC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`replace` is generating a brand new `String` object every time it is called, since strings in Java are immutable and so modifications cannot be made "ìn-place". Also, you're adding that `String` to an `ArrayList` which will hold a reference to the new object, preventing it from being collected.

Comment: But how do I properly create Strings with the replace instruction without running out of memory? Let's say I need "foo 1", "foo 2", ... "foo 20000". I am assuming concat has the same problem.

Comment: If you actually need to store 20000 Strings, then you need memory for 20000 Strings. If that's more memory than you have, you'll have to think of a way around that (maybe generating and using them in sets of 5000 or something along those lines.) If you need to generate, use, and then get rid of 20000 Strings, don't store each one in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: With `s = lorem;`there is no problem in storing 20000 Strings in memory. My problem is that I need strings generated dynamically.

Comment: Right, because with `s = lorem` you're not creating a new string. You're just assigning a reference to `lorem` to `s`. So you still only have one string.

Comment: @Xavi, dlev has touched the issue at it's core.  If you don't have too much memory, the key is not how to use more memory than you have, it's how to do the same amount of stuff with less.  There is probably not a need to store all the strings beforehand, you could probably produce one string, act on it, and then dispose of it (looping 20000) times.

Comment: @Edwin: Are you both saying I can't do it without having memory problems? (by the way, have a look at the question update please)

Comment: @Xavi, I see lots of "why can't I do this?", coupled with "I need to do this because this is what I need to do?" but no, "Here is the problem I'm trying to solve."  If the goal of your program is only to hold 20000 strings in memory, great.  If your program does anything beyond holding strings in memory, odds are good you're able to avoid the mass storage.  This is an "artificial" problem in the sense it's not requirement for delivery or correct function (unless you can demonstrate that it is).

Comment: @Edwin: This is not an "I need to do this because this is what I need to do" question! :) As I said, I'm doing a workaround. I only wanted to be sure there wasn't a proper way to deal with strings I wasn't aware of. Next time I'll try harder to make myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Xavi, depending on what you're looking for, if you are only going for string storage, you can use the string intern(..) methods, but doing so will cost you CPU cycles to scan the VM for any duplicates of that string.

Answer (score 2):

Because `String`'s are immutable, calling `foo.replace("foo", lorem)` will create a new `String` each time.  In the example where you simply set `s = lorem`, no new `String` is created.

Also, System.gc() is simply a recommendation to the VM, and it will in no way guarantee a garbage collection.  There is nothing you can do to force a garbage collection. (other than using up all available memory that is)

Comment: But how do I properly create Strings with the replace instruction without running out of memory? Let's say I need "foo 1", "foo 2", ... "foo 20000". I am assuming concat has the same problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `String`'s?  Could they be int primitives instead?

Answer (score 2):

System.gc() is a hint to the garbage collector to run again, when it has the time.

That said, the garbage collector only collects unreferenced objects, and all the strings you generated are still being held by the object `array`.  It is entirely possible that you might add the lines after `System.gc()`

```
for (String item : array) {
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

Which would have proven the garbage collector's wisdom in not destroying the strings.

In the event that you have some true need to reuse a String, you can trade off CPU cycles for possibly lower memory footprint with String intern methods (which will scan allocated strings for duplicates and return a reference to the single kept string if found.

You might argue that in your case the garbage collector hint could invoke compile time optimization techniques to realize that array is not being used downstream and thus act to destroy the strings before they would normally be dereferenced at the end of the program; however, it would add side effects that would appear quite strange in some runtime environments (like debugging sessions).

In the end, it is not possible to accurately perform reflection, code stepping, compile binding to source code, and various types of reflection with such exotic compile time optimization.  That said, Java optimizes itself pretty well considering how many features you get out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `System.gc()` does not force the garbage collector to run.  It is merely a hint that you would like it to run at some point in the future.